# Overriding Qt's mousePressEvent breaks moveEvent parameter

Tags: c++, qt, mouseevent

I've implemented a bound sub-window class, catching the moveEvent in order to prevent the user from dragging the sub-window out of the MDI area. Then I tried to override the mousePressEvent function. This causes moveEvent's to go haywire. E.g. clicking on the sub-window's title bar would cause it's position to jump 100+ pixels away.

I'm using Qt 5.13.0, VS Community 2017 (15.9.15), and Windows 10 Pro.

This happens with a MainWindow to which I've added an MDI Area in QT Creator 4.10.0 (Community). A minimal application demonstrating the problem can be downloaded from https://drive.google.com/file/d/15MBy7ArT7o9NjtOvcKD5TefT-Icndmb4/view?usp=sharing

Commenting out the mousePressEvent function makes moveEvent behave again.

The bound sub-window's header file is

```
#pragma once

#include <QMdiSubWindow>

class boundSubWindow : public QMdiSubWindow
{
protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override;

protected slots:
    virtual void moveEvent(QMoveEvent* moveEvent);
};
```

The body is

```
#include <QMoveEvent>

#include "boundsubwindow.h"

bool isSubInMdi(QRect& sub, QRect& mdi)
{
    return (sub.left() >= mdi.left() && sub.right() <= mdi.right() &&
            sub.top()  >= mdi.top() && sub.bottom() <= mdi.bottom());
}

void boundSubWindow::moveEvent(QMoveEvent* moveEvent)
{
    QPoint subPos = moveEvent->pos(),
           oldPos = moveEvent->oldPos();
    QRect  subRect = QRect(subPos.rx(), subPos.ry(), this->width(), this->height()),
           mdiRect = this->parentWidget()->rect();

    if (!isSubInMdi(subRect, mdiRect))
    {
        QRect oldSubRect(oldPos.rx(), oldPos.ry(), this->width(), this->height());

        if (isSubInMdi(oldSubRect, mdiRect))
            this->move(moveEvent->oldPos());
    }
}

void boundSubWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->button() == Qt::RightButton)
    {
        auto me = (boundSubWindow*)this;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `auto me = (boundSubWindow*)this;` suppose to do?

Comment: Nothing. In the original program the code goes on to do something with the window, which I've removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the nature of `QMdiSubWindow` my guess would be that its own `mousePressEvent` implementation does a fair bit of important work -- so you need to call it from within your own `mousePressEvent` implementation...

```
void boundSubWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->button() == Qt::RightButton)
    {
        auto me = (boundSubWindow*)this;
    }
    QMdiSubWindow::mousePressEvent(event);
}
```